# Using js, css and html in wordpress

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, wordpress

I have been experimenting with wordpress for the last 3 days now and I am trying to understand the way some plugins are working. I have downloaded the "INSERT html Snippet" a plugin that is allowing me to use html, css and js.

I have found a source code from online sources in which all of these attributes are used. I have created a file inside the plugin with the current source code. When i add the current file in one of my pages the css and html is working just fine as the widget is created and designed all fine, the problem though is with the javascript code as it seems that is not working. The link that i found the source code is the following: https://bootsnipp.com/snippets/4nZWx

I have structured the code in the following way inside the file that i am loading from the plugin:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
<style>
img {
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}

.slider {
  width: 90vmin;
  height: 90vmin;
  -webkit-perspective: 100vmin;
          perspective: 100vmin;
  margin: auto;
  -webkit-perspective-origin: top center;
          perspective-origin: top center;
  position: relative;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.slider__item {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  padding-top: 15vmin;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 0.18s ease;
  transition: -webkit-transform 0.18s ease;
  transition: transform 0.18s ease;
  transition: transform 0.18s ease, -webkit-transform 0.18s ease;
}
.slider__item:nth-child(1) {
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0vmin);
          transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0vmin);
  -webkit-transition-delay: 0s;
          transition-delay: 0s;
  z-index: 7;
}
.slider__item:nth-child(2) {
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, -15vmin);
          transform: translate3d(0, 0, -15vmin);
  -webkit-transition-delay: 0.05s;
          transition-delay: 0.05s;
  z-index: 6;
}
.slider__item:nth-child(3) {
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, -30vmin);
          transform: translate3d(0, 0, -30vmin);
  -webkit-transition-delay: 0.1s;
          transition-delay: 0.1s;
  z-index: 5;
}
.slider__item:nth-child(4) {
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, -45vmin);
          transform: translate3d(0, 0, -45vmin);
  -webkit-transition-delay: 0.15s;
          transition-delay: 0.15s;
  z-index: 4;
}
.slider__item:nth-child(5) {
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, -60vmin);
          transform: translate3d(0, 0, -60vmin);
  -webkit-transition-delay: 0.2s;
          transition-delay: 0.2s;
  z-index: 3;
}
.slider__item:nth-child(6) {
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, -75vmin);
          transform: translate3d(0, 0, -75vmin);
  -webkit-transition-delay: 0.25s;
          transition-delay: 0.25s;
  z-index: 2;
}
.slider__item:nth-child(7) {
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, -90vmin);
          transform: translate3d(0, 0, -90vmin);
  -webkit-transition-delay: 0.3s;
          transition-delay: 0.3s;
  z-index: 1;
}
.slider__item:nth-child(8) {
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, -105vmin);
          transform: translate3d(0, 0, -105vmin);
  -webkit-transition-delay: 0.35s;
          transition-delay: 0.35s;
  z-index: 0;
}
.slider__image {
  width: 100%;
  height: 80%;
  background-color: #999;
  border: 1.5vmin solid #eee;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  box-shadow: 0px 3vmin 3vmin rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75), 0 -1.5vmin 2.7vmin rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75);
  overflow: hidden;
  display: block;
  -webkit-transition: opacity 0.2s ease, -webkit-transform 0.18s ease;
  transition: opacity 0.2s ease, -webkit-transform 0.18s ease;
  transition: transform 0.18s ease, opacity 0.2s ease;
  transition: transform 0.18s ease, opacity 0.2s ease, -webkit-transform 0.18s ease;
  -webkit-transform-origin: bottom center;
          transform-origin: bottom center;
}
.slider__caption {
  height: 20%;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8);
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
      -ms-flex-align: center;
          align-items: center;
  -webkit-box-pack: center;
      -ms-flex-pack: center;
          justify-content: center;
}
.slider__btn {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  width: 9vmin;
  height: 9vmin;
  margin: 2vmin auto;
  border-right: 2vmin solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8);
  border-bottom: 2vmin solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.65);
  z-index: 100;
  cursor: pointer;
  -webkit-transform: perspective(10vmin) rotateX(-30deg) rotateZ(45deg);
          transform: perspective(10vmin) rotateX(-30deg) rotateZ(45deg);
}
.slider__btn:active {
  border-right-color: #dd6;
  border-bottom-color: #dd6;
}
</style>
</head>
<html>
<body>

<div class="slider">
  <figure class="slider__item"><img class="slider__image" src="https://unsplash.it/600/360?image=#{itemsImg}"/>
    <figcaption class="slider__caption">Image - 533</figcaption>
  </figure>
  <figure class="slider__item"><img class="slider__image" src="https://unsplash.it/600/360?image=#{itemsImg}"/>
    <figcaption class="slider__caption">Image - 623</figcaption>
  </figure>
  <figure class="slider__item"><img class="slider__image" src="https://unsplash.it/600/360?image=#{itemsImg}"/>
    <figcaption class="slider__caption">Image - 419</figcaption>
  </figure>
  <figure class="slider__item"><img class="slider__image" src="https://unsplash.it/600/360?image=#{itemsImg}"/>
    <figcaption class="slider__caption">Image - 490</figcaption>
  </figure>
  <figure class="slider__item"><img class="slider__image" src="https://unsplash.it/600/360?image=#{itemsImg}"/>
    <figcaption class="slider__caption">Image - 695</figcaption>
  </figure>
  <figure class="slider__item"><img class="slider__image" src="https://unsplash.it/600/360?image=#{itemsImg}"/>
    <figcaption class="slider__caption">Image - 458</figcaption>
  </figure>
  <figure class="slider__item"><img class="slider__image" src="https://unsplash.it/600/360?image=#{itemsImg}"/>
    <figcaption class="slider__caption">Image - 702</figcaption>
  </figure>
</div>
<div class="slider__btn"></div>

<script>
$(function(){
    var btn = $(".slider__btn");

    btn.on("click",function(){
        $(".slider__item").first().clone().appendTo(".slider");
        $(".slider__image").first().css({transform: "rotateX(-180deg)", opacity: 0});
        setTimeout(function(){
            $(".slider__item").first().remove();
        },200);
    });
});
</script> 

</body>
</html>
```

Can anyone please help me?

Thanks in Regards

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you must change the `$` for a `jQuery` alias. Wordpress it's a little bit fussy with this. Anyway, without seeing a live example it's difficult to assure that this is the problem.
Why don't add this code to the theme maybe creating a new template or modifying one?